# How can i do a push notification service with a webservice on Ionic?

Tags: json, api, ionic-framework

Ok, i need some help…
I’m finishing an app but i need some kind of service who looks in my backend and when my JSON changes (this JSON contain some valors who changes if the user get notifications) send to that user a pushmessage to the terminal even the app is off. Something like an ajax call every ‘x’ seconds but doing it in mobile.

I’ve past a few days searching but i’m completly lost and i need some kind of tutorial, example or something.

I’ve searched in the forum but i doesn’t find anything.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you want using Events that will be triggered when something changes in your backend (if you're using a modern framework like Laravel you can do it easily)

Inside the event it will see that a change is made and then send a push notification to that device with whatever service you used (acm, pusher,...etc)

Comment: I'm using symfony. The thing i'm developing it's an webapp with an iframe but when i receive a change on that i wanna send a push message to the mobile app... But i don't know how.

Comment: symfony has an implementation for Events, check it out:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html